# How to use multiple choices to run a job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have created a jenkins pipleine to run a job (e.g. Pipeline A runs job B). Within job B there is multiple parameters. One of the parameters is a choice parameter that has multiple different choices. I need pipeline A to run job B with all of the different choices at once (Pipeline A runs Job B with all of the different choices in one build). I am not too familiar with using the Jenkins declarative syntax but I am guessing I would use some sort of for loop to iterate over all of the available choices?

I have searched and searched through Stack overflow/google for an answer but have not had much luck.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Pipeline Matrix](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/)? Not sure if this is what you need, but for me it looks like an alternative of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the options in a separate file outside your jobs, in shared library:

```
// vars/choices.groovy

def my_choices = [
    "Option A",
    "Option B", // etc.
]
```

You can then use these choices when defining the job:

```
// Job_1 Jenkinsfile

@Library('my-shared@master') _ 

properties([
    parameters([

        [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
            name: 'MY_IMPORTANT_OPTION',
            choices: choices.my_choices as List,
            description: '',
        ],
...

pipeline {
    agent { any }

    stages {
...
```

In Job 2, you can iterate over the values:

```
// Job_2 Jenkinsfile

@Library('my-shared@master') _ 

pipeline {
  agent { any }

  stages {
    stage {
      for (String option : choices.my_choices) {
        build job: "Job_1", 
          wait: false, 
          parameters: [ string(name: 'MY_IMPORTANT_OPTION', value: option) , // etc.
          ]
```

Job_2 when it is run will asynchronously trigger a number of runs of Job_1 each time with a different parameter.